# how to avoid changing value when stack push is called on a adress

Tags: c, pointers, stack

so I have this code and the stack_push implementation takes in an address,
so whenever I change the cnt value everything else changes as well, how do I prevent that?
i want it to x= 5 then x= 2
i cannot change my stack_push function since its an opaque structure

```
int main(void){
  struct stack *a = stack_create(10*4);
  int cnt = 10;
  int i=cnt;
  while (cnt != 1){
    cnt = i/2;
    stack_push(a,&cnt);
    i = cnt;

  }
  int *x = stack_pop(a);
  x = stack_pop(a);
  stack_destroy(a);
}
```

Comment: Use seperate variables. The stack API given to you stores a reference/pointer to the original variable. So you need to push a different variable each time.

Comment: Since you don't show a proper [mcve] it's hard to do anything but guess, but the guess is that the stack contains *pointers* to `int` (instead of `int` *values*). Since you're adding pointer, all pointers will be exactly the same: a pointer to `cnt`. Since all pointers are the same, the value will seem to be the last value assigned to `cnt`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `stack_create` is manipulating, it implies the following:

- When placing data to the stack, the data must be copied into `malloc` block
- When pulling data from the stack, the data must be freed when it's no longer in use

Most likely, the stack_* has a function to check when the stack is empty. Consider the following code to push multiple values to the stack, and retrieve them, following the above points.

Consider the following

```
int main(void){
  struct stack *a = stack_create(10*4);
  int cnt = 10;
  int i=cnt;
  while (cnt != 1){
    cnt = i/2;
    //// COPY data to newly allocated block
    int *data = calloc(sizeof(*data)) ;
    *data = cnt ;
    stack_push(a,data);
    i = cnt;
  }

  //// Retrieve all items
  while ( !stackIsEmpty(a) ) {
     int *x = stack_pop(a);
     printf ("%d\n", *x) ;
     //// Free the copied data
     free(x) ;
  } ;
  stack_destroy(a);
}
```